# Whitespace below images css

Tags: image, whitespace, space

I got a project to fix image issues for a client and this one has bugged me for days now. The site is http://www.fonolive.com. Some of the small icons that display on the front page show white space below image.

I have tried the following on

```
 img{

    }

  display:block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  vertical-align:top;
  vertical-align:middle;
  vertical-align:sub;
  font-size:0px;
  display:inline;
  line-height:0px;
```

and more.

The only thing that seems to work is if I set the image height to say 130%, but the problem is recurrent on several pages across the site and this is an absolute no no.

The other solution I have worked on is resizing the images in php or using javscript etc, but that only works if javascript is enabled and seems too complex of a solution.

Please, try it in firebug and let me know what is wrong. Thanx and appreciate every input

Comment: When you say whitespace, do you mean the gray that's below some images?  The issue is that you're trying to fit images that are of different shapes into boxes of a uniform shape.

Comment: And you're definitely going to need to resize those images on the backend before displaying them on the front page. Resize and crop.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think if you refresh you will see some images with a significant whitespace of about 2-3px and more for some. It looks like that is what I'll have to do, resize and crop. I wanted to force fit the images temporarily with a quick css fix. Thanks.

Comment: They really don't look good stretched anyway.  Use GD or imagemagick to scale and crop them to the proper size.  It'll also cut waaay back on the bandwidth required for that page.